# Invoke Action created from Expression<Action> in another scope

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, delegates, lambda

Consider the following simple example:

```
private Action _action;

public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = "test";
    Expression<Action> exp = () => MessageBox.Show(msg);
    _action = exp.Compile();
    msg = "testC";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _action();
}
```

When button2 is clicked, I see `testC`.

My question is:

I want to store actions to be run later. Can I safely store the delegate that `compile()` creates and use it whenever I want?

My question is mostly about method arguments. I am not aware on how they are stored (by ref or by value), of if they can they be cleared by GC in the meantime. In general I doubt that this is the correct approach. Also, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) isn't of much help.

*I am creating a JobManager that supports High priority actions to be executed. There is a stack of default actions and some high priority that need to be added. This part is where I register the high priority job (using a lambda -> get the method -> create delegate -> store it -> run in when needed). I am not sure if this is the right approach to store the action anyway.*

Comment: Why are you creating an expression and compiling it instead of just creating an action from the lambda in the first place?

Comment: @Servy As noted `I doubt that this is the correct approach`. Thanks about that tip. I was led to this approach and got stacked about argument usage.

Comment: All you need to do is use `_action = () => MessageBox.Show(msg);`.  As for whether it stores the reference or the value, just executing the code (which you did) gives you an answer, does it not?

Comment: I need a little bit more theory. I can see it works though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.
The lambda expression creates a *closure* that holds references to the local variables that it uses from the outer function.

This closure is referenced in the delegate's `Target` property.
As long as you hold a reference to the delegate, those variables won't be GC'd.

For a more detailed look at how this works, see [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html).